# Append is null error?

Tags: jquery

**edit**: I don't get any errors anymore, but executing this code:

```
$("#button-container").append(".tbox");
```

only places ".tbox" text next to the button that is created when you open the modal. It doesn't get appended to the modal.

[Here is the demo page](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos)

Clicking the "open modal" link, a button is created. I tried to append that to the modal with no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: when I open your demo I get an immediate `element is null` error on this line `element.addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);`

Comment: not looked at demo page, but did you mean `$("#button-container").append($(".tbox"));`

Comment: @Chimoo that doesn't make any difference in jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB oh right, didn't know that...

Comment: and page dosn't have jQuery.js in it either

Comment: Hi guys, the touchstart null you get is because that page will eventually serve for tablets. The huge wall of script I have on my index page is to reduce the wait time when clicking buttons.

Comment: @pufAmuf: It's null because `document.getElementById("tclose")` is null.

Comment: @pufAmuf: Did you include jQuery on your page?

Comment: That's interesting..... I forgot to include jQuery :) Sorry for that!

Comment: I tried it now, and all that happens is that the text `.tbox` is added at the end of the button. Setting the z-index manually to 9999 doesn't bring it forward, so I don't think that it's really appended anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new FastButton(document.getElementById("tclose"), funclose);
```

Seems there's no "tclose" id element in the page. When you run the script, the "tclose" button is nowhere in the page.

As @Chimoo said you should use:

```
$("#button-container").append($(".tbox"));
```

and this should append your element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Advicer, but I will remove that button anyway :) I have edited my question to the problem I face now, which is a button I plan to append to the modal.

Comment: If he answered the question for you, it might be more appropriate to mark him as having answered it and then submit a second question

Comment: But that wasn't the question I had in the first place. I really do appreciate his comment, which is why I upvoted him :)

Comment: Actually i didn't answered his question. I was noticing him the page had some errors, so the problem could be there. I'll give a look, and if I can answer his question I'll edit my post.